# Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be affine subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ with $M_1 \cap M_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $\dim(M_1 \cap M_2)=\dim(M_1)$. Then $M_1 \subset M_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $M_1 \cap M_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $\dim(M_1 \cap M_2)=\dim(M_1)$. Then $M_1 \subset M_2$. I tried to prove by contradiction and took an element in $M_1$ and assumed it was not in the intersection, but it did not work. I also tried to use the dimensions of linear subspaces to create these affine subspaces, but it did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen A subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $M = \{m\} + W$ for some $m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and some subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in M_1\cap M_2$

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ two linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $$M_i=a+U_i(i=1,2)$$

By definition, $\dim M_i=\dim U_i$.

On the other hand, we obviously have that$$M_1\cap M_2=a+U_1\cap U_2$$

So, by hypothesis, we have that $$\dim U_1\cap U_2=\dim U_1$$

$U_1\cap U_2$ is a linear subspace of $U_1$. Therefore $$U_1\cap U_2=U_1$$

So$$M_1=a+U_1=a+U_1\cap U_2\subset M_2=a+U_2.\square$$

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality assume that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Pick a basis of $M_1 \cap M_2$, say $v_1, \ldots, v_k$. But then $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ lie in particular in $M_1$, so by the dimensionality assumption they span $M_1$ and are therefore a basis, whence $M_1 \subseteq M_2$.

Comment: Can we assume that they are linear subspaces? As far as I know, an affine subspace does not need to be a linear subspace.

Comment: @fezaninsonu They need not be linear to start, but will be after you translate by $-v$ for any $v \in M_1 \cap M_2$, and $-v + M_1 \cap M_2 = (-v + M_1) \cap (-v + M_2)$, thus the "without loss of generality."

Comment: I really couldn't get it.

Comment: @fezaninsonu Any affine subspace containing 0 is linear, so you can make any affine subspace linear just by translating. But translation is an affine isomorphism (its inverse being given by translating back), so many problems about affine spaces reduce to problems about linear spaces. This is the case here: Translating by $-v$ is an isomorphism on $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_1 \cap M_2$, so you might as well solve the problem for linear spaces and then translate to get the result for affine spaces (you might also say that the problem is translation-invariant).

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thank you so much.